# Target HTML content before ":" and change styling

Tags: javascript, html

There were a couple of examples similar to what I wanted to do - but their content was formed differently so I couldn't figure out how to change the javascript to apply to my project.

I have a HTML file that is autogenerated by PHP via a JSON dump. I'm trying to style it to have a little bit prettier. At the moment I have the PHP script create the HTML file with three arguments, the HTML5 template wrapped around the content which just gets dumped into the body.

This means the content is nothing more than a list with 
 in it that I can't directly edit. So i'm looking obviously with javascript to make everything before the colon bold.

```html
<body>
<h2>Data</h2>
 IP: 212.141.10.200<br/>Serial: C02SQ5REEYY0<br/>Date: Sun 25 Jun 2017 13:41:07 BST<br/> 
</body>
```

Should be

**IP:** 212.141.10.200

**Serial:** C02SQ5REEYY0

**Date:** Sun 25 Jun 2017 13:41:07 BST

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression on `innerHTML` of element:

```
var body=document.body
body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replace(/([a-z]+):/gi, "<b>$1</b>:");
```

Here is a working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/hs5abphz/

I think that it is the simplest, but not the best solution. It may corrupt your attributes. For example `<span style="font-color: #333;">` will transform to `<span style="font-<b>color</b>: #333;">` which is not correct.

Comment: This looks like it should work but i'm getting an error "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'div.innerHTML')"

Comment: Sorry, just realised it needs to go AFTER the content of course. 
One thing i've noticed, if there are multiple words before the colon (which there isn't in the example) it only bolds the last word, anyway to do everything before colon?

Comment: @DannyShepherd you can change regular expression. For example in such way: https://jsfiddle.net/hs5abphz/2/ `(/(^|>)([^<:]+):/gi, "$1<b>$2</b>:")`